# Which voltage stabilizer can be used to power the ATmega 328 and the BMP280 sensor?

Tags: arduino, sensor, atmega

I have a connection diagram of the [BMP280](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmp280-ds001.pdf) to an ATmega328, but I do not know which voltage stabilizer to put on the input of the ATmega328, so that it would be powered like an Arduino from 3 to 9 V, and how to get 3.3 V from the ATmega328's VCC output to power the sensor.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If operation all the way down to 3 V is required, a linear regulator as the other answer recommends won't cut it.

To be 100% clear: I would still recommend a linear regulator for this application, if a higher voltage cutoff is tolerable. Low dropout regulators could make the cutoff as low as about 3.5 or 3.6 V. But if you absolutely cannot tolerate a cutoff above 3 V, read on:

---

A switching regulator is the only way to *increase* a DC voltage. Since your input range straddles your output voltage, you need a regulator that can both step up the voltage (when it's too low) and step down the voltage (when it's too high). There are a couple topologies that can do this.

- A four-switch buck-boost is the most straightforward; it's basically a buck converter followed by a boost converter sharing the same inductor. However, it requires four switches as the name implies (two can be diodes, at a slight loss of efficiency), which you may want to avoid.
- A SEPIC, or the related zeta converter, requires only two switches (one can be, and usually is, a diode), but requires two inductors (preferably but not necessarily coupled) and an additional capacitor. Tuning the control loop can be a little tougher for these since they have a higher-order filter response.
- The two-switch buck-boost and non-isolated Ćuk converter both can only produce negative output voltages, which is probably not what you want here.
- A flyback converter again requires only two switches (one is usually a diode), but requires a loosely-coupled transformer. These flyback transformers are readily available, but can be physically larger than inductors used for other topologies. The flyback topology is more well known for being used to generate high voltages, but there's nothing saying you can't use it for low voltages like 3.3 V. It will have somewhat higher ripple than the other options here, however. If you don't require output isolation, you can use direct feedback from the output, rather than the more common optocoupler feedback.
- Other transformer-based topologies like the forward converter (including active-clamp forward) and isolated Ćuk converter exist as well; these again require transformers, and are more complicated than most of the other options above, so I wouldn't recommend them for this and won't go into further detail.

My personal recommendation for this application would be a SEPIC if you're not too concerned about efficiency, or a four-switch buck-boost if you are. The reasoning is thus: SEPIC controllers are readily (although somewhat pricily) available from LT/Analog and TI, both of which have good simulation tools for their parts  (LTspice and TINA-TI/PSPICEforTI respectively), so you can make sure everything will theoretically work before actually laying out a PCB. However, the SEPIC controllers I've seen are almost never synchronous; they rely on a diode for one of the switches, and that means efficiency losses. Four-switch buck-boost controllers are available from the same manufacturers, including synchronous versions that use four MOSFETs instead of two FETs and two diodes, and should be easier to use. However, the increased part count (if it's not a monolithic converter, at least) may be a detriment.

There should be a step-by-step walkthrough for designing a SEPIC or four-switch buck-boost in the datasheet of any good controller IC, including instructions on choosing inductors and switches, so don't be put off by the apparent complexity!

Answer (score 0):

1. A linear voltage regulator will do as there's little power consumption: For example [Onsemi NCP1117DT33T5G](https://www.digikey.fi/short/02hdc50v). With this type of a device you cannot go below 3.3 V and must leave room for drop out voltage. Lowest voltage with this part would be 4.5 V.
2. Atmega328 does not have power outputs, they are all inputs that need to be supplied with power.
3. Atmega328 cannot run on 16 MHz crystal with 3.3 V power supply (Edit: Looks like it can can use the external crystal, using a clock divider. FW needs to take it into account.)
4. Ground connections for the parts need to be connected together

Comment: 3.3 volts must be supplied from the main VCC input to power the BMP280, and from 2.7 to 5.5 volts to power the atmega

Comment: about 3.: It can't run at 16 MHz, but it can run from a 16 MHz clock, using the internal clock divider.